# I want to read a csv file with pandas, I want to skip rows but I want to keep the original line numbers

Tags: pandas, read-csv

I want to keep track of the original line numbers.

I tried using the skiprows parameter of pd.read_csv(). The original line numbers are not preserved so.

If I start reading at row 100, then the first row number in the in the obtained dataframe will be 0. Moreover I want to preserve the original header.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] (with 5 rows to skip instead of 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a range index and want to keep the header and skip the next `n` rows, use a `range` in `skiprows`:

```
file_path = io.StringIO('''A,B
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
''')

n = 2
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0, skiprows=range(1,n+1))
df.index += n
```

Output:

```
   A  B
2  5  6
3  7  8
```

Comment: *NB. I had to post a new answer since a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425430) prevented me to edit my other one.*

Answer (score 0):

Use Indexnumber as true:

```
df.to_csv('MyLists.csv', sep=",", index=True)
```

Comment: I wanted to do this when reading, not when writing - tx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example, extract dataframe from csv file

```
import io
import pandas as pd

txt = '''1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
'''

file_path = io.StringIO(txt)
```

**Code**

Add the skipped number to the RangeIndex.

```
n = 2 # skip number
df = (pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, skiprows=n)
      .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.index + n))
)
```

df(skip 2 rows from `txt`):

```
    0   1
2   5   6
3   7   8
```

Comment: Thank you, for me this seems to be the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the original index, why no just slice **after** reading the data?:

```
pd.read_csv(filename).iloc[100:]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, the only drawback being that we make a copy.

Comment: @M.Nemes this is the only way if you have an arbitrary index (if you read with `index_col=...`). The other option, **if you have a range index** would be to skip when reading and to increment the index: `df = pd.read_csv(your_file, skiprows=100) ; df.index += 100`, then no copy.

Comment: Yes, I have only the range index (that's why I try to preserve the original values) - so this df.index += 100 is a nice trick.

Comment: @M.Nemes I just saw your edit, if you want to skip n row after the header, then see [this alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185062). No need to read the file twice.

Answer (score 0):

Combinining the solutions of [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway) and [@Panda Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20430449/panda-kim) and adding the preservation of the header (that I later put into my original question):

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import io
    
    txt = '''A,B
    1,2
    3,4
    5,6
    7,8
    '''
    
    file_path = io.StringIO(txt)
    h = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, nrows=1)
    h = h.iloc[0].tolist() # preserve the header
    
    file_path = io.StringIO(txt)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=0, skiprows=n)
    df.columns = h # restore the header
    df.index += n  # restore the line numbers
    print(df)
    
    #    A  B
    # 2  5  6
    # 3  7  8
```